# How to create exFAT or NTFS RAID 1

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ntfs, raid, exfat

I am looking for a way to create a RAID 1 Volume from macOS Sierra with a format that will be readable from both Mac and Linux.

Using DiskUtility I can not seem to find a way to format the RAID in another other formats other than JHFS+. Even from the command line. Maybe I am wrong and just have not found how to do it. Please let me know if I have missed it.

Other things I have considered is spinning up a virtual machine and/or Docker container and just doing it from Linux this way. Because I know how I can do it from `mdadm`.

I have also looked around for some third party software that can do this, but most of the ones that I have found are more than I'm willing to pay, since I know I can do it inside of Linux for free.

Lastly, I am trying to use `luks` to encrypt the RAID after it is set up. I am not sure any answers would prevent this, but just thought I would mention it in case it impacts the answers.

Comment: I’ve been unable to find confirmation, but I do not believe a software RAID created in disk Utility can be used in another OS. Have you been able to use this RAID set on Linux?

Comment: @The_Stewart No, only because I have not RAID'd them together yet. This is my "Step 1"; which I stopped once I realized the only filesystem formats that diskutil allows you to select from is JHFS+. Though when formatting disks, you do have the options of exFAT and other non-apple only formats. I also looked at the cli version to see if it had exFAT options, sadly no. I think the only options is to do it from Linux (which I don't have access to a Linux machine other than a VM or docker container) or find a 3rd party software that does it. Unless there is other options I dont know if yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a RAID set using two USB sticks with Disk Utility in macOS Sierra 10.12.6. While I was only presented with Mac OS Extended options during the setup, once the RAID set was created I could erase it and choose another format.

[image: Disk Utility screenshot showing a selected RAID set and formats such as Mac OS Extended, ExFAT, and MS-DOS.]

After formatting the volume as ExFAT, I was able to store data on the RAID set.

However, I can't say what standard of RAID is used creating these sets. If you intend to connect the RAID set to another OS other than macOS, your millage may vary.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! This totally worked! I would totally upvote this, but my rep is too low. I did mark it as an accepted answer though. Thanks again!